# Not updating CSS effect when jQuery in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, typescript

sorry guys, I'm a fresher in TypeScript. I have the following code, I think I have made some mistakes,

HTML

```
<script src="hello.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

TypeScript

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
interface mysite {
    name: string;
    url: string;
}
function Show(site: mysite) {
    return site.name + " at http://" + site.url + "/";
}

window.onload = () => {
    var el = document.getElementById('content');     
    el.innerHTML = Show({ name: "Delphian", url: "stackoverflow.com/users/602714/delphian" });     
    //$(el).css("color", "red");
    $("el").css({"color": "red" });
};
```

I tried many ways to get this CSS effect on HTML DIV element, but not getting. what is the mistake I have made? please suggest..
updating the Javascript

```
function Show(site) {
    return site.name + " at http://" + site.url + "/";
}

window.onload = function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('content');
    el.innerHTML = Show({ name: "Delphian", url: "stackoverflow.com/users/602714/delphian" });
    $("#content").css({ "color": "red" });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use

```
$(el).css({"color": "red" });
```

as Steve Fenton mentioned
or directly select the element with JQuery's selector mechanics:

```
$("#content").css({"color": "red" });
```

"#element" selects the an element with this id, ".element" selects all elements with this class and "element" selects all elements with this tag.

Comment: try `$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#content").css({"color": "red"}; 
});`
and I made a Little mistake, you have to write "#content" of course and not "#el"

Comment: where I have to user $( document ).ready(function(), inside of window.onload or outside ?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but did you include jQuery in your HTML file and do you have any Content in your div to reflect the changes?

Comment: outside of the onload function. It is something similar to to onload, only "better". It waits for all the DOM to be loaded.

Comment: also check your Browser's JavaScript console window for any Errors. I am not so sure about TypeScript, but `function Show(site: mysite)` (**site: mysite**) is unknown to me in normal JavaScript.

Comment: getting this error JS console "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "

Comment: Well this means that you jQuery was not loaded or referenced. Do you have a `<script src="path_to_jquery_file.js"></script>` (like your hello.js) in your HTML file? This should be included before the hello.js. The line `///<reference path ...>` does not include the jQuery Code.

Comment: yes, you are right, we need to add jQuery file externally... :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor typo:

```
$("el").css({"color": "red" });
```

Should be

```
$(el).css({"color": "red" });
```

Using `"el"` will select elements of type `<el>`, whereas passing the variable `el` will wrap the element in a jQuery object.

You could use:

```
var myHtml = Show({ name: "Delphian", url: "stackoverflow.com/users/602714/delphian" });
$('#content').css({"color": "red" }).html(myHtml);
```

[Plain JavaScript demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrx3T/) - but should work just the same in TypeScript too.

Comment: Sorry Steve, now its not showing the DIV element, code should be     var el = document.getElementById('content');  
    var myhtml = Show({ name: "Delphian", url: "stackoverflow.com/users/602714/delphian" });   
    $('#content').css({ "color": "red" }).html(myhtml);

Comment: any wrong with window.onload function? If I have include that function on jsfiddle JS not working

Comment: can I get a simple example, how jquery working in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
$("el").css({"color": "red" });
```

With this

```
$("#content").css({"color": "red" });
```

this will work for you.